# Post-Registration, post-meta hook?

Tags: hooks, user-meta, user-registration

Is there a hook in WP to access meta data of a user JUST after they have registered and meta data has been added to the database?

I was reading to use `profile_update`, but wouldn't that be invoked every time they update their profile? I just want something to occur the moment that they have registered, and the users meta has been entered in to the database.

Please let me know,

Thanks!

Tre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `user_register`

```
add_action('user_register', 'wpse42506_user_register', 10, 3);
function wpse42506_user_register( $user_ID ) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

If you want to just use the user information, you can use `get_userdata`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

If you need more control, you can initiate a new `WP_User`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at that too. But someone said that it won't give me access to meta values like first name and last name, so I didn't try. Was that false?

Comment: It passes the $user_ID. So you will have access to everything about the user. I updated my answer with more information

Comment: Cool, I'll have a look. I guess that post I read was a lie :\ Or miss-informed. Thanks!